# Playframework 2.2 : How to pass argument directly to another method inside of view file?

Tags: java, forms, helper, playframework-2.2

This code below has been extracted from http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1-RC2/JavaFormHelpers

```
@(myForm: Form[User])
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.submit()) { 
@helper.inputText(myForm("username"))
@helper.inputPassword(myForm("password"))
}
```

I have two questions

1. How can I pass two values("username", "password") directly to the
   "submit()" method? Like,

   ```
   submit(inputText("username"), inputPasword("password")) ?
   ```
2. I've followed some tutorials then I've realized that "form
   variables" were always declared as global in the controller. Just
   like the code I included.

Why doesn't just binds to form locally and passes it directly to submit()?
Why should exist a global variable?

Is declaring the variable "myForm" as global in the controller is kind of good practice?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`routes.Application.submit()` in this example defines the URI where this form will send its contents upon clicking 'submit' button. `inputText` and `inputPassword` are form elements. When you post the form, all its contents are sent along already (in the request body) - you will be able to get their values via binding the form with the same structure to the request in `routes.Application.submit()` method.

Comment: Yes. I'm aware that `inputText` and `inputPassword` are form elements and all its contents are sent along. My point is if I should always bring the form `@(myForm: Form[User])` from controller and then fill it with the contents and then submit? Why that? It not possible to omit `@(myForm: Form[User])` in the scala template and submit data?

Comment: No, you can specify parameters for a form in any way you like (and you aren't required to use parameters per se). In this example the Form parameter is used only to set up some initial values for the elements.

Comment: I've been searching about what you said but I couldn't find an example. How can I create Form just inside of template and then submit?

Comment: I've been searching about what you said but I couldn't find any example. Or I'm not understanding what you said. How can I create Form just inside of template and then submit(return that Form to controller)? Could you show me an example?

Comment: No, you don't create the Form inside of template. What you create there is a normal form that's send along with your request. You create a Form inside of the method that is processing this request, and binding it either with `form().bindFromRequest()`, as described in Play docs http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.3/JavaForms -- or just with `request().body().asFormUrlEncoded()`